# Are there any other millets similar to little millet in taste?

Tags: grains, cereal

I have seen several types of millets in few ethnic stores in Texas. Few of the names are Proso Millet, Barnyard Millet, Kodo Millet, Pearl Millet, Finger Millet, Little Millet. I tried Little Millet and I liked it since it does not have a strong flavor like Finger Millet. However, Little Millet is not easily available where I live, are there other millets that have a mild taste?

Answer (score 0):

You can use barnyard millet in place of little millet ,